# Better Exposed Filters

Tags: views

[image]I have created a view block to display filter options. But in BEF settings I dont get check box options. Can anybody help me out.

Thank you in advance
embeeke

Comment: Can you please add screenshot?

Comment: Hello and welcome. You stated a fact. Could you please now ask a question?

Comment: how to add filters as checkbox list using BEFs.

Comment: Have you read the BEF module documentation it says: "Most BEF features are available with filters that have a limited number of options" Make sure the field you using as exposed filter have limited number of options.

Comment: Can you please elaborate @MutantMahesh

Comment: @embeeke BEF's documentation says that BEF features are available for filters that have limited number of options, that means any field which have a limited number of option can be exposed as select list or checkboxes e.g term reference field have limited terms then it can be exposed as BEF. but not node title which can't be exposed as BEF checkboxes because there can be any number of nodes on a drupal site.

Comment: @embeeke from your screenshot it looks like you are using term reference field as exposed filter, then BEF should give checkboxes option. If its not working in your case then try with dev version of BEF module.

Comment: @mutantMahesh Hi i tried d dev version. But nothing changed.

Comment: Can you provide the detailed info of the field you are using as exposed filter?

Comment: i am using 5 fields with term references. added them in view fields, exposed them as filters and in BEF settings i am not able to get the checkbox options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried on my local with

- drupal 7.30-dev
- views 7.x-3.7
- better exposed filter 7.x-3.0-beta4

Added term reference field in article content type. Created a view, added this term reference field as exposed filter i was able to get the checkboxes for tid.

**Make sure the term reference field setting is set to "Dropdown" and Use Ajax options is set to "yes".**

[image: reference field setting and use ajax]
[image: reference field setting set to dropdown]

After setting term reference field setting to "Dropdown" i was able to see the "Checkbox/radio buttons" options in better exposed filter setting.

[image]

Comment: Hey thank you so much, i got it. But the auto submit feature is not working. can you guide me on this.. Thank you

Comment: In BEF setting there is option for Autosubmit. Check that option. you can see that in above screenshot. Please accept answer if that helped.

Comment: ya i checked autosubmit option. and another problem is, i get an error after creating the view "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator."

Comment: This error occurs when I select dropdown as filter criteria setting

Comment: Have you created those option in hook_form_alter? or modified the select list options in other way? This error occur due to type mismatch. This error occur when you add new value in a select list which is other then the type of value allowed in that list. For example if you add 'string' value in select list option if only 'integer' values are allowed in that select list.

Comment: no i have not created anything in hook_form_alter

Comment: There are lots of questions asked for this problem. See here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=An+illegal+choice+has+been+detected you may find you answer. Please accept my answer if that helped. Thanks